# Existence of a large divisor of the product of all primepowers in the interval [p/2, p], with the divisor restricted to some moduloclass

Tags: nt.number-theory

The title almost says it all;

Let $p$ be some large prime. Does there exist a $d$ such that the following three things hold?;

1) $d$ divides the product of all primepowers in the range $[p/2, p]$.

2) $\log d$ is asymptotically equal to $p/2$.

3) $d \equiv \dfrac{p+1}{2} \pmod{p}$.

Comment: Can you even show that there is d that satisfies conditions 1 and 2? Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2011.11.02

Comment: Sure. Just take d to be the product of all the primepowers, which equals $e^{p(1 + o(1))}$

Comment: Its that last assertion I suspect.  I can believe e^(p - something small), but I am unsure that something small is a constant.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2011.11.02

Comment: It's not a constant.. But it's smaller than $\epsilon p$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ and large enough $p$. This is just equivalent to the prime number theorem, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am doing rough mental calculations, so I may be coming up short; I feel that for p < 10^6, any such divisor d is strictly less than e^p, never mind its modulo class.
I could move on to your question if you could provide a p and a d contrary to my feeling.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.02

Comment: Oops, I (hopefully) noticed my mistake. Edited accordingly

Comment: My concern is that there are more primes closer to p/2 than to p, and that the missing factors of 2 will overpower any prime powers that you have,  I am willing to be proved wrong, but the size of the product will be crucial to your problem in any case, so make sure that is locked down.  I don't think the PNT gives enough to give you 1 !and 2 : Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.02

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I can follow you. It's not necessary that log d is larger than p/2. I only need them to be asymptotically equal. Or, relaxing the question somewhat, at least larger than cp for some c > 0

Comment: Further, if you hope for 1 2 and 3 to hold, you need the product of the powers and primes to be more like pe^p.  Without it, one of 2 or 3 is likely to fail.  In my amateur but experienced opinion.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2011.11.02

Comment: I realize that you don't need the product of the primes and primepowers in the interval )p/2,p( to be as big as e^p.  My concern is the product still falls asymptotically short of e^p, so that you won't even get 2.  My intuition says that in order to hope for both 2 and 3 given 1 that you will need the product to be significantly bigger than e^p.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2011.11.02

Comment: log(e^p) ~ log(pe^p), right?

Comment: product ~ e^p is certainly false, yes. But that doesn't imply that log(product) ~ p is false

Comment: I just now refreshed the page, and saw the p/2 in number 2.  I feel more optimistic about the existence of such a d now.  With p instead, it seems hopeless.  For large p, some perspectives conflate p and log(p) + p.  I don't know yet if such conflation is necessary or desired.
Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.02

Answer (score 2):

The question seems very difficult. First of all, the product $P$ of all prime powers in $(p/2,p)$ is $e^{p(1/2+o(1))}$, see below for a proof. Therefore the question can be reformulated as follows: is there a subset $S$ of pairwise coprime integers such that (1) each element of $S$ divides a prime power in $(p/2,p)$, (2) the product over $S$ is $e^{o(p)}$ and congruent to $2P$ modulo $p$. Indeed any $d$ can be written as $P$ divided by the product over such an $S$ and vice versa.

Now the problem acquires a combinatorial flavor. One would look at the group $G=(\mathbb{Z}/p)^\times$, consider the subset $T\subset G$ represented by the divisors of the prime powers in $(p/2,p)$ and try to represent a particular residue class as a product of very few elements from $T$. Note that already $T$ is rather small, and $G$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)$ whose structure depends on the prime factorization of $p-1$. Even the simpler question seems difficult to answer: why does the subgroup generated by $T$ contain the residue class $2$ modulo $p$? Note that, by Artin's conjecture on primitive roots, this becomes the following question for infinitely many $p$'s: why does $T$ generate $G$?

To see my claim on the size of $P$, observe that $P$ is the same as the least common multiple of all prime powers in $(p/2,p)$, since each prime has at most one power there. On the other hand, the product $R$ of all primes in  $(\sqrt{p},p/2)$ is coprime with $P$, hence $PR$ divides the least common multiple of all prime powers in $(1,p)$. This shows that $PR\leq e^{p(1+o(1))}$, whence also $P\leq e^{p(1/2+o(1))}$ by $R\geq e^{p(1/2+o(1))}$. On the other hand, $P$ is at least as large as the product of all primes in $(p/2,p)$ which is $e^{p(1/2+o(1))}$.